# calling c# script in sql procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a simple C# script as part of an SQL procedure, but can't seem to figure it out.
Some pointer on how to get this started would be great.
Thanks in advance

This is my C# script, which simply reads in the first 30 lines of a .txt file (@filename) which is set in the SQL procedure, and outputs it to a new .txt file (file.txt) the SQL procedure then deals with the rest.

It runs fine with the @filename hard coded, but I need it to use the set @filename from the SQL procedure to read in the file and to be called and run from the SQL procedure

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace GenericLoad
{
    class ReadFromFile
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            if(File.Exists(file.txt))
            {
                File.Delete(file.txt);
            }
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@filename).Take (30). ToArray();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Append);
                TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                Console.SetOut(sw);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.SetOut(tmp);
                sw.Close();
            }
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's even possible? You can create SQLCLR functions and procedures, but this would be completely wrong in this case , require elevated privlieges *and* disabling some security features. Why don't you simply do all the work in your application or use SSIS ? If you only want to ouput some rows, why not use bcp to export them?

Comment: If you want to load lines from a file, you should try the BULK INSERT statement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I approached it in exactly that way! and have arrived at a much simpler and satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0):

So I just used a bulk insert into my temp table of the first 30 rows of the text file and then decide on the headers

```
--Bulk insert first 30 lines of the finalreport.txt file into dbo.tmp_finalreportheader

    SET @bulkCommand = ' BULK INSERT ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.tmp_finalreportheader
    FROM ''' + @fileName + '''
    WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
          FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
          DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
          MAXERRORS = 0,
          FIRSTROW = 1,
          LASTROW = 30)'
    EXEC(@bulkCommand)

    ALTER TABLE dbo.tmp_finalreportheader
    ADD lineId INT IDENTITY(1,1)

    PRINT 'dbo.tmp_finalreportheader table created'

/**************************************************************************************************************
Select the string from row n where the column headers are i.e. Name, ID...
Using function dbo.BreakStringIntoRowsTab
(where line = [DATA] + 1)
**************************************************************************************************************/

    DECLARE @RowNumber INT = (SELECT lineId + 1 FROM dbo.tmp_finalreportheader WHERE line='[DATA]');
    DECLARE @Data INT=(SELECT lineId + 2 FROM dbo.tmp_finalreportheader WHERE line='[DATA]');

    SET @myString=(SELECT line FROM dbo.tmp_finalreportheader WHERE lineId=@RowNumber)

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpHead') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpHead

    SELECT *
    INTO #tmpHead
    FROM dbo.BreakStringIntoRows(@myString);

    SELECT @sqlColumns = COALESCE(@sqlColumns + ', ', '') + '[' + Headers + '] NVARCHAR(100)' FROM #tmpHead;

    SELECT @sql = 'CREATE TABLE tmp_Import (' + @sqlColumns + ')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```